# Compare 2 array members count in jsonb

Tags: database, jsonb

Have table with columns (User_ID, A_D). A_D column is jsonb.

```
User_ID | A_D
1 | "{"agreements": [1, 7], "disagreements": [13]}"
2 | "{"disagreements": [13, 100]}"
4 | "{"agreements": [14, 177, 22], "disagreements": [3, 2]}"
5 | "{"agreements": [77]}"
6 | "{"agreements": [24, 14, 89, 102], "disagreements": [200]}"
```

i need get users, who have more members in "agreements" array than in "disagreements" array.

those user ids must returned

```
1
4
5
6
```

Comment: You can use the [`json[b]_array_length()` function(s)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) directly, like: `jsonb_array_length(A_D -> 'agreements') > jsonb_array_length(A_D -> 'disagreements')`

Comment: @pozs - How I missed this function, I think you should make this as an answer

Comment: @OtoShavadze yeah, probably. But I usually hesitate with answers as simple as this. I would love to see some [more effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) from OPs.

Answer (score 2):

With the [`json[b]_array_length()` function(s)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), it is as simple as:

```
WHERE jsonb_array_length(A_D -> 'agreements')
    > jsonb_array_length(A_D -> 'disagreements')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you need this:

```
select t1.User_ID, t1.cnt, t2.cnt   from (
    select User_ID, count(*) as cnt from ( 
        select User_ID,  jsonb_array_elements_text(a_d->'agreements')  from your_table 
    ) arr1
    GROUP BY User_ID
) t1
LEFT JOIN (
    select User_ID, count(*) as cnt from ( 
        select User_ID,  jsonb_array_elements_text(a_d->'disagreements')  from your_table
    ) arr2
    GROUP BY User_ID
) t2
ON t1.User_ID = t2.User_ID 
where coalesce(t1.cnt, 0) > coalesce(t2.cnt, 0)
```